# Is this version correct?

Tags: hadith, isnad

I need help with the following variants :

> .....Then it is said to him: 'Sleep.' So he said: 'Can I return to my family to inform them?' They say: '**Sleep as a newlywed, whom none awakens but the dearest of his family, until Allah resurrects him from his resting place.**'" ([Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1071))

And....

> .....He will say: Leave me so that I may go and give glad tidings to my family. He will be told: Dwell. ([Sunan Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4751))

Is the former as correct as the latter? It's graded Hasan while the latter is Sahih and without the highlighted part. From whom is this addition narrated and is it accurate?

Comment: Well it might be that the additions in the first might be somewhat doubtful, but this is just thinking out loud without any real research effort.